# Serializing no more possible of OpenJPA Entity throws UnsupportedOperationException, DetachedStateManager.isProvisional(DetachedStateManager.java:760)

Tags: java, serialization, jpa, red5, openjpa

My framework seems to have issues with a special entity that constantly fails to get serialized with an exception.

Entity:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/persistence/beans/basic/Server.java?view=markup

My theory: The serializer uses the enhanced class from OpenJPA, and it cannot serialize it.
 
But I have no idea how this can only happen with this entity and all other work fine.

Exception:

```
WARN: Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap.get(BeanMap.java:390)
    at org.red5.io.amf.Output.writeObject(Output.java:348)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeObjectType(Serializer.java:332)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeComplex(Serializer.java:173)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:119)
    at org.red5.io.amf.Output.writeObject(Output.java:348)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeObjectType(Serializer.java:332)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeComplex(Serializer.java:173)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:119)
    at org.red5.io.amf.Output.writeObject(Output.java:348)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeObjectType(Serializer.java:332)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeComplex(Serializer.java:173)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:119)
    at org.red5.io.object.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:60)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encodeNotifyOrInvoke(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:800)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encodeNotifyOrInvoke(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:747)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encodeInvoke(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:735)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encodeMessage(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:514)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encodePacket(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:147)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encode(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:119)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPMinaProtocolEncoder.encode(RTMPMinaProtocolEncoder.java:48)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.filterWrite(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:322)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterWrite(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:509)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1400(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.filterWrite(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:808)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.filterWrite(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:734)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callPreviousFilterWrite(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:509)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireFilterWrite(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:501)
    at org.apache.mina.core.session.AbstractIoSession.write(AbstractIoSession.java:494)
    at org.apache.mina.core.session.AbstractIoSession.write(AbstractIoSession.java:439)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection.write(RTMPMinaConnection.java:308)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.Channel.write(Channel.java:136)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.Channel.write(Channel.java:105)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onInvoke(RTMPHandler.java:428)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:132)
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.messageReceived(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:716)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:245)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:434)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:796)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:75)
    at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:780)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:772)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:714)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DetachedStateManager.isProvisional(DetachedStateManager.java:760)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a serialization problem? Because I don't see anything related to serialization in the stacktrace..

Comment: because the framework hangs in an endless loop after the serialization try. You can also read it from the stack trace. Somehow a function is invoked that is "Unsupported". That is at least the way I read it. Also the usage of "reflect" is for me an indicator that there is some lookup of a method during the serialization of the object. It might be that this _not_ the standard Serializer by java but some custom. I can't say that for sure. Still suprising that any other Entity works fine just this one fails.

Comment: It's not a serialization issue because if it is as you say about a custom serializer then other objects should fail. And it's hard to say why this is occurring without seeing some more code. Can you post the code where you serialize this? Or where you think serialization is occurring...

Comment: Oh and the entity that is failing as well..

Comment: the link to the entity is the first one of my post.

Comment: the rest is red5 related, I do nothing else as for example writing a method that returns a server object.

Comment: Sorry I missed that link. The problem is in the calendar instance I think. I found this link. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/red5interest/OrxzXMgkf2Q/wKmezGs8zZIJ. If you can use a Date tehre instead it should work..

Comment: That is not possible. Cause in another framework (Axis2) Date will be parsed as => dd-mm-yyyy and calendar as dd-mm-yyyy hh:ss

Comment: Axis2 folks claim that this is the correct way to do it and we use this entity with both frameworks as return type of some rpc calls. (And of course we need the time part of the entity's attribute too ...)

Comment: Well it's either time to get into red5 and fix the problem or use a Date instance variable and convert it to a Calendar in the getter although I don't know how feasible you think that is..